# Visual Studio 2015 reinstall a package

Tags: visual-studio-2015

after installing VS2015 update 1 RC, i can no more load C# project. Error is:

```
CreateInstance failed for package [CSharpPackage]

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I tryed a repair operation without success, i tryed the clearcache options without success.

Any idea how to manually delete/reinstall this package ?

Comment: I'd tried to repair the vs. now waiting....

Comment: After reinstalling still have this problem. But to restart  vs again,it's be well